# How do I remove this vertical space?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, amsmath, tcolorbox

Here's my code -

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{syntonly}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tabularray}
%xparse package needed for physics package to work properly
\usepackage{xparse}

% Font encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
%For colours
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

%Defining colours
\definecolor{Rust}{HTML}{BF3100}
\definecolor{Orange yellow}{HTML}{EEB902}


\definecolor{Vermillion}{HTML}{D52D0B}
\definecolor{Imperial Red}{HTML}{E63946}
\definecolor{Honeydew}{HTML}{F1FAEE}
\definecolor{Powder Blue}{HTML}{A8DADC}
\definecolor{Atomic Tangerine}{HTML}{F39C6B}
\definecolor{Selective yellow}{HTML}{FFB703}
\definecolor{Prussian blue}{HTML}{033063}
\definecolor{Raisin black}{HTML}{272838}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%COLOURSCHEME%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%COLOURSCHEME%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Definitions header
\definecolor{Yale blue}{HTML}{084B83}
% definition boxes colour [colback=Powder blue!50!white, colframe=Powder blue!50!white]
\definecolor{Powder blue}{HTML}{BBE6E4}


%Examples header
\definecolor{Indian red}{HTML}{DB5461}
%Examples box [colback=Unbleached silk!65!white, colframe=Unbleached silk!65!white]
\definecolor{Unbleached silk}{HTML}{FFD9CE}


%Margin notes colour (Linen!60!white)
\definecolor{Linen}{HTML}{F9EAE1}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%COLOURSCHEME%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%COLOURSCHEME%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%Package for fixing bugs when using marginnotes
\usepackage{mparhack}

%For Garmond font
\usepackage{garamondlibre}

%Float package
\usepackage{float}

%Continue to enumerate
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

%layout package
\usepackage{layout}

%geometry package
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={23cm,28cm}, right=9.3cm, left=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=3cm, marginparwidth=4.8cm, marginparsep=1.5cm, headheight=0cm}

%marginparpush=2cm

%fancyheaders
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\chaptername\ \thechapter}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\thepage}

%Packages for Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution
\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}


%Wrapping lines of text package
\usepackage{seqsplit}


%For the unit of rate constant table
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, siunitx}

%Package for striking out terms in a calculation
\usepackage{cancel}

\usepackage{xfrac}


%Package for inserting figures in margin notes
\usepackage{sidenotes}

%packages required for sidenotes package to work correctly
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{l3keys2e}
\usepackage{changepage}

%package for landscape tables
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}

%Defining a new column type for the alkyl groups table
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.4cm}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.7cm}}
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}}

%Defining a new column type for the cis-trans isomers table
\newcolumntype{E}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{7cm}}
\newcolumntype{F}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}


\newcolumntype{G}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{8cm}}

%For the free radical substitution reaction
\newenvironment{f}{$\displaystyle\aligned}{\endaligned$}

%to fix overlflowing margin notes
\usepackage{marginfix}



% Diagrams from mathcha
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
For example - 
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=Powder blue!50!white, colframe=Powder blue!50!white]
\begin{align*}
    \ce{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}Br2(l) & ->[\Delta H_{at}^{\ominus}]Br(g)}\\
    \ce{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}Cl2(g) & ->[\Delta H_{\text{at}}^{\ominus}] Cl(g)}\ \ \ \ \Delta H_{at}^{\ominus}=+121\ \unit{kJ\ mol^{-1}}\\
    \ce{Na(s) & ->[\Delta H_{at}^{\ominus}] Na(g)}\ \ \ \ \Delta H_{\text{at}}^{\ominus}=+109\ \unit{kJ\ mol^{-1}}\\
     \ce{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}H2(g) & ->[\Delta H_{\text{at}}^{\ominus}] H(g)}\ \ \ \ \Delta H_{at}^{\ominus}=+218\ \unit{kJ\ mol^{-1}}
\end{align*}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

This generates the following -
[image]

Any ideas on how I can remove the extra blue vertical space?

Comment: why `\usepackage{syntonly}` ???

Comment: Please, next time simplify your preamble to just required packages.

Comment: I see nothing in blue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use option `ams align*` in tcolorbox options and avoid using `ams align*` environment inside.

```
\documentclass[12pt,x11names]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{Powder blue}{HTML}{A8DADC}


\usepackage{garamondlibre}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

%geometry package
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={23cm,28cm}, right=9.3cm, left=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=3cm, marginparwidth=4.8cm, marginparsep=1.5cm, headheight=0cm}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
For example - 
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=Powder blue!50!white, colframe=Powder blue!50!white, ams align*]
%\begin{align*}
    \ce{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}Br2(l) & ->[\Delta H_{at}^{\ominus}]Br(g)}\\
    \ce{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}Cl2(g) & ->[\Delta H_{\text{at}}^{\ominus}] Cl(g)}\ \ \ \ \Delta H_{at}^{\ominus}=+121\ \unit{kJ\ mol^{-1}}\\
    \ce{Na(s) & ->[\Delta H_{at}^{\ominus}] Na(g)}\ \ \ \ \Delta H_{\text{at}}^{\ominus}=+109\ \unit{kJ\ mol^{-1}}\\
     \ce{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}H2(g) & ->[\Delta H_{\text{at}}^{\ominus}] H(g)}\ \ \ \ \Delta H_{at}^{\ominus}=+218\ \unit{kJ\ mol^{-1}}
%\end{align*}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `array` environment

```
\documentclass[12pt,x11names]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}    
\definecolor{Powder blue}{HTML}{A8DADC}
\usepackage{garamondlibre}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={23cm,28cm}, right=9.3cm, left=3cm, top=2.5cm, 
     bottom=3cm, marginparwidth=4.8cm, marginparsep=1.5cm, headheight=0cm}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\noindent   
For example - 
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=Powder blue!50!white, colframe=Powder blue!50!white]
        \arraycolsep=1.6pt
        $\begin{array}{rl>{\qquad}l}
        \ce{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}Br2(l) & ->[\Delta H_{at}^{\ominus}]Br(g)}\\
        \ce{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}Cl2(g) & ->[\Delta H_{\text{at}}^{\ominus}] Cl(g)} & \Delta H_{at}^{\ominus}=+121\ \unit{kJ\ mol^{-1}}\\
        \ce{Na(s) & ->[\Delta H_{at}^{\ominus}] Na(g)} & \Delta H_{\text{at}}^{\ominus}=+109\ \unit{kJ\ mol^{-1}}\\
        \ce{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}H2(g) & ->[\Delta H_{\text{at}}^{\ominus}] H(g)} & \Delta H_{at}^{\ominus}=+218\ \unit{kJ\ mol^{-1}}
        \end{array}$
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]